# Provider-independent crypto in Java?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, jce

I'm trying to write a program in Java that will digitally sign database entries prior to insertion. I would like for the program to be algorithm-independent - ideally, the user would specify the JCE provider and algorithm as arguments at runtime.

Is there a way to do this? I've been testing with the BouncyCastle provider, and the code runs fine when I dynamically register it:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

However, when I try to statically register the provider by adding the following lines to the end of my security/java.policy file, I get the error: `java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: BC` when I try to get an instance of a Security object using the provider.

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.2=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

Specifically, I added those lines to `/etc/java-7-openjdk/security/java.policy` (which is linked to `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.policy`). This is on Ubuntu 12.04. I also tried just adding the BouncyCastleProvider as the first entry and got the same error.

Am I configuring the static registration wrong or is what I am attempting impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are adding the static registration into the wrong file.
Use `security.policy` instead of `java.policy` within the same folder.

See: https://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation

Comment: Simple answer: yes, easy mistake to make: for sure, fit for SO: certainly. Hopefully it shows up in search engines.